# im trying to loop through array of coordinates and remove elements from array if they within x miles of any other element in in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, unset

example:

```
        $arr =Array(
        Array("name1","lat1","lng1"),
        Array("name2","lat2","lng2"),
        Array("name3","lat3","lng3"),
        Array("name4","lat4","lng4"),
        Array("name5","lat5","lng5"),
        ) ;
```

I have a function that will return miles apart from 2 different locations

```
        function is_within_x_miles($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {
              return $milesApart;  
          }
```

the idea is to return an array that makes sure every location is x miles apart from each other

Actual runnable code:

```
        <?php

        $arr =Array(Array(" exclusive-care-2"," 38.677892"," -121.31073"),
        Array(" the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale"," 38.689974"," -121.297324"),
        Array(" norcal-medicine-man-top-shelf-cards-accepted"," 38.718435"," -121.290412"),
        Array(" the-sanctuary-delivery-5"," 38.694406"," -121.302111"),
        Array(" canna-couriers-1"," 38.68"," -121.27"));


        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
          // loop through inner array
          foreach ($arr as $key2 => $value2) {
            // skip if same element in array
            if($key == $key2){
              continue;
            }
            // if distance is more than 2 miles remove from array
            $distance = distance($value[1],$value[2],$value2[1],$value2[2]);
            // visual output
            within_distance($distance, 2, $value[0], $value2[0]);
            if($distance > 2){
              unset($arr[$key]);
            }
          }
        }


        // show array
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($arr);
        echo '</pre>';


        /* funtions*/
        // function to calculate distance between two points
        function distance($lat1, $lng1, $lat2, $lng2) {
          if (($lat1 == $lat2) && ($lng1 == $lng2)) {
            return 0;
          }
          else {
            $theta = $lng1 - $lng2;
            $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
            $dist = acos($dist);
            $dist = rad2deg($dist);
            $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
              return $miles;  
          }
        }

        // function to show if distance is more than x miles
        function within_distance($distance, $miles, $name, $name2) {
            if ($distance > $miles) {
                echo '<pre><b>'.$name .' <span style="color:green;"> is '.$distance.' from  '.$name2.' </span></b></pre>';
              }else{ 
                echo '<pre><b>'.$name .' <span style="color:red;"> is '.$distance.' from  '.$name2.' </span></b></pre>';    
            }
        }
```

Output is

```
        exclusive-care-2  is 1 from   the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale 
        exclusive-care-2  is 3 from   norcal-medicine-man-top-shelf-cards-accepted 
        exclusive-care-2  is 1 from   the-sanctuary-delivery-5 
        exclusive-care-2  is 2 from   canna-couriers-1 
        the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale  is 2 from   norcal-medicine-man-top-shelf-cards-accepted 
        the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale  is 0 from   the-sanctuary-delivery-5 
        the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale  is 2 from   canna-couriers-1 
        norcal-medicine-man-top-shelf-cards-accepted  is 2 from   the-sanctuary-delivery-5 
        norcal-medicine-man-top-shelf-cards-accepted  is 3 from   canna-couriers-1 
        the-sanctuary-delivery-5  is 2 from   canna-couriers-1 
        canna-couriers-1  is 2 from   the-sanctuary-delivery-5 

        final array:

        Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  the-sanctuary-delivery-5
                    [1] =>  38.694406
                    [2] =>  -121.302111
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  canna-couriers-1
                    [1] =>  38.68
                    [2] =>  -121.27
                )

        )
```

The final array can't be correct because **the-sanctuary-delivery-5** is under 2 miles from **canna-couriers-1**

I feel like as soon as the first interval ran **the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale** should have been removed from the array.

Comment: You should break out of the inner loop when you remove the element from the array.

Comment: If 2 locations are less then 2 from each other, shouldn't they *both* be removed from the array?

Comment: That's why `the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale` is still in the array. You only remove `exclusive-care-2` from the array during the first iteration. Then when you get to ``the-re-up-citrus-heights-orangevale` in the outer loop, `exclusive-care-2` is no longer there, so you don't get that distance.

Comment: @Barmar "If 2 locations are less then 2 from each other, shouldn't they both be removed from the array?" i need at least a starting point i would think

Comment: You should probably avoid modifying an array while you are looping through it. Consider making a copy of the array instead. Also @Barmar has a point. If two locations are close, which one gets removed? This problem may be more complex than you expect.

Comment: Your `if` statement condition is backwards. You're supposed to remove when the distance is under 2, not when it's over 2.

Comment: Or use `array_filter()`

Comment: @Barmar "You should break out of the inner loop when you remove the element from the array." if i break out of the inner loop it won't run it against the rest of the elements in the array right?

Comment: You don't need to, because you've already removed that element from the array. Why do you need to get the distance from anything else?

Comment: @Barmar  locationA, locationB, locationC 
Start with Location A is within x of locationB? if true delte locationB now check locationC etc. is what i was thinking but not sure what to do

Comment: You're deleting location A. There's no need to check if location C is within x of location A, because location A has already been removed.

Comment: how would i delete locationB?